# Keyboard doesn't work, title bars are gone

Tags: input

Been using Ubuntu Studio the last 5 days. Now, all of a sudden the title bars on top of the windows are gone and the keyboard can't write anything.

Numlock scrolllock capslock are all toggling normally (their lights go on and off on the keyboard). I was even able to zoom in and out of a webpage in Firefox by holding Ctrl and scrolling the mouse middle wheel button. But other than the password at startup, I can't write anything and Alt Tab is not working either. Alt works (brings out menu bar), Ctrl Q works as well.

Also the title bars are missing from the windows I guess? Such that I can't move any windows around. Also, clicking a window will make it active but will not bring it to the front.

KDE plasma 5.24.7

KDE frameworks 5.92.0

Qt 5.15.3

Kernel 5.15.0-60-lowlatency (is it always low latency? There was only one Ubuntu option in the bootup menu)

Graphic processor llvmpipe

Comment: Same happened to me several times already. Still haven't found a fix.